# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError for Processing with Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, processing

whenever I run the main class as shown below,

```
 package gardeningmania;

 import processing.core.PApplet;
 import java.io.File;

 public class GardeningMania {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    PApplet.main(new String[]{/*"--present",*/ "gardeningmania.Game"});
   Game.main("null"/*"gardeningmania.Game"*/);
    File currentDir = new File("."); getAllFilse(currentDir);
}
}
```

I get this error:

**ERROR CODE**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

```
at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:437)
at sun.java2d.Disposer.add(Disposer.java:139)
at sun.java2d.Disposer.addRecord(Disposer.java:107)
at sun.awt.image.BufImgSurfaceData.initRaster(Native Method)
at sun.awt.image.BufImgSurfaceData.createDataIC(BufImgSurfaceData.java:256)
at sun.awt.image.BufImgSurfaceData.createData(BufImgSurfaceData.java:86)
at sun.awt.image.BufImgSurfaceManager.<init>(BufImgSurfaceManager.java:55)
at sun.awt.image.SurfaceManager.getManager(SurfaceManager.java:78)
at sun.java2d.SurfaceData.getPrimarySurfaceData(SurfaceData.java:273)
at sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.createGraphics(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:180)
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.createGraphics(BufferedImage.java:1154)
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getGraphics(BufferedImage.java:1142)
at processing.core.PFont.<init>(PFont.java:227)
at processing.core.PFont.<init>(PFont.java:328)
at processing.core.PApplet.createFont(PApplet.java:6560)
at processing.core.PApplet.createFont(PApplet.java:6488)
at gardeningmania.Game.<init>(Game.java:497)
at gardeningmania.ImageLoader.<init>(ImageLoader.java:12)
at gardeningmania.Game.<init>(Game.java:524)
at gardeningmania.ImageLoader.<init>(ImageLoader.java:12)
```

Can anyone explain what this error message means?

Comment: What is this program about? And where is the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.StackOverflowError indicates that the stack of methods invocation has reached it's maximum size. It usually indicates an error exiting recursion (invoking methods infinitely without having them finish) for instance.

As for you case we need to see `gardeningmania.Game` constructor as this is where the problem happens, otherwise we can only speculate about this.